# Footnote in figure caption using ccaption.sty with svmono.cls

Tags: footnotes

I tried to place footnote in figure's caption it is working fine with book.cls but not working with svmono.cls

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ccaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{my_figure.jpg}
 \caption{My caption \protect\footnotemark.}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{Text...}

\end{document}
```

Kindly guide me to fix this error.

```
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ccaption/ccaption.sty
Package: ccaption 2011/08/07 v3.2c Extended captioning and new floats


! LaTeX Error: Command \captionstyle already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Ty
```

Comment: where did you find the `svmono` class? Apparently it is not available in TeXlive 2017 (Windows).

Comment: I downloaded "svmono" from this http://ftp.utia.cas.cz/pub/staff/studeny/monogr/svmono.cls

Answer (score 1):

The error is perfectly described in the log file that you copy-pasted here:

> Package: ccaption 2011/08/07 v3.2c Extended captioning and new floats
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \captionstyle already
> defined.

The problem comes from your `ccaption` package that defines the `\captionstyle` command, which already exists (probably defined by your class).

So the solution is to remove the `\usepackage{ccaption}`, which anyway you don't seem to use.